# String is not replaced in CreateUserWizard Registration Email

Tags: c#, asp.net

My website allows users to create accounts.

Upon creating, an email verification with a URL will be send to the user's email.

Problem: The sending of email worked but unfortunately the verification URL did not appear.

And for

```
<a href="<%VerifyUrl%>"<%verifyUrl%></a></p>
```

there is a green curly line beneath "<%VerifyUrl%>", stating that this file could not be found.

This is the source code of Login.aspx :

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail(object sender,MailMessageEventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser userInfo = Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard1.UserName);

    //Construct the verification URL
    string verifyUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Page.ResolveUrl("~/Verify.aspx?ID=" + userInfo.ProviderUserKey.ToString());

   // Replace <%VerifyUrl%> placeholder with verifyUrl value
    e.Message.Body = e.Message.Body.Replace("VerifyUrl", verifyUrl.ToString());
}
```

This is the html file that what user would see in their email:

```
<h2> Welcome to My Website!</h2>
<p>
    Hello, <%UserName%>. You are receiving this email because you recently created a new account at my 
    site. Before you can login, however, you need to first visit the following link:</p>
<p>
    <a href="<%VerifyUrl%>"><%verifyUrl%></a></p>
<p>
    After visiting the above link you can log into the site!</p>
<p>
    If you have any problems verifying your account, please reply to this email to 
    get assistance.</p>
<p>
    Thanks!</p>
```

Comment: You replace "VerifyUrl", but the template value is <%VerifyUrl%>. Are you sure the replacement is working correctly?

Comment: Sorry. for the <a href="<%VerifyUrl%>"><%verifyUrl%></a> , the <%VerifyUrl%>"> have a green curly line and it state that it could not be found.

Comment: Ah, OK. But yet - you have 'verifyUrl' in the string, while the replace string is VerifyUrl. Is this a paste error? Replace is case-sensitive.

Comment: So all the verifyUrl change to VerifyUrl? from v to V?

Comment: I changed it all the VerifyUrl. But the same problem still appearing. The code still can run and send out email. Just that the email was missing the URL.

Comment: What exactly is sent in the email? <%VerifyUrl%> ? or nothing? Could it be that the e.Message.Body is being escaped somehow? When debugging what do you see in the contents of Body ?

Comment: It should have send the verification Url in the email. But right now, the URL doesn't appear in the email. All the words inside the html file appears apart from the URL.

Comment: Ok, when you debug - does e.Message.Body change after Replace() is called? What do you have in the email.Message.Body right before sending it? Also, do you check the email in an email client? It is possible that the email client strips the tag somehow...

Comment: e.Message.Body does not have any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are attempting to replicate the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.maildefinition%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in MSDN. If not, you may want to reference that example for some pointers.

A couple of points to make:
Realize that the `<% %>` syntax is special in asp.net. In this context the `<%UserName%>` statement has a special meaning to the control, which fills it with the UserName just created (reference the example above). Your `<%VerifyUrl%>` has no special meaning to the control. It is part of the email body and ASP.NET treats it as merely some characters in the string. (This is why the green curly line is entirely unimportant) You are searching for the string of characters `VerifyUrl` only. I'm not certain why your replace function isn't working, but if it did your `<a>` tag wouldn't work properly anyway, because your href value would be wrapped in `<% %>`.
If, instead, you changed your code to

```
e.Message.Body.Replace("<%VerifyUrl%>", verifyUrl.ToString())
```

I believe that your Replace would work correctly and you would end up with a usable URL.

As a side note, I have found personally that using `String.Format` can be easier and more reliable to implement in these situations as long as you remember to order your parameters correctly.

Edit:
I just noticed that this question is over 6 months old and the answer may not help you now, but I hope someone else can get some use out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a workaround is:

```
    Dim Email = RegisterUser.Email
    Dim UserID = Membership.GetUser(RegisterUser.UserName).ProviderUserKey
    Dim user1 As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(RegisterUser.UserName)
    Dim verifyUrl As String = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Page.ResolveUrl("~/Account/ActivateUsers.aspx?UserID=") + UserID.ToString + "&Email=" + RegisterUser.Email)
    e.Message.Body = "<!DOCTYPE html>"
    e.Message.Body += "<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">"
    e.Message.Body += "<head>"
    e.Message.Body += "<title></title>"
    e.Message.Body += "<style>body{text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:10.0pt;font-weight:normal;text-align:left;overflow: visible;}</style>"
    e.Message.Body += "</head>"
    e.Message.Body += "<body>"
    e.Message.Body += "<p>Thank you for registering. To activate your account please click on the link below:<BR /><BR />"
    e.Message.Body += verifyUrl
    e.Message.Body += "</p>"
    e.Message.Body += "</body>"
    e.Message.Body += "</html>"
    e.Message.To.Add(Email.Trim())
    e.Message.Subject = "xxxxxx Account activation Email"
    Dim smtpMail As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient()
    smtpMail.Send(e.Message)
```

Hope this helps somebody.