# Including variables other than <%Username%> and <%Password%> in PasswordRecovery email

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to include an additional variable in the email generated via the PasswordRecovery control in my C# web application. I have a User_Profile table which contains a user's first and last names but I can't work out how to pass that information to the HTML email template via variable usage. `<%Username%>` and `<%Password%>` work fine, but all I get is the placeholder when trying to pass firstName. Here's what I have:
ASPX:

```html
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfFirstName" runat="server" />
<asp:PasswordRecovery ID="ResetPassword" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnSendingMail="ResetPassword_SendingMail">
<MailDefinition BodyFileName="~/EmailTemplates/HTMLEmailPWReset.html" IsBodyHtml="true" Subject="Your password has been reset" />
  <UserNameTemplate>
    <h2>Reset my password</h2>
    <p>Forgot your password? Enter your User Name below.</p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="User Name" runat="server" />
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="User Name is required" ValidationGroup="ResetPassword" Display="Dynamic" />
      <asp:Label ID="FailureText" runat="server" CssClass="field-validation-error" EnableViewState="False" />
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" CommandName="Submit" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" ValidationGroup="ResetPassword" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <asp:Button ID="cancel" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-block" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="cancel_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </UserNameTemplate>

  <QuestionTemplate>
    <h2>Reset my password</h2>
    <h4>Identity Confirmation</h4>
    <p>Please answer the following security question to receive your new password.</p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label><strong>User Name:</strong>
      </label>
      <asp:label ID="UserName" CssClass="form-control form-control-static" runat="server" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label><strong>Question:</strong>
      </label>
      <asp:label ID="Question" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label><strong>Answer:</strong>
      </label>
      <asp:textbox ID="Answer" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AnswerRequired" ControlToValidate="Answer" ErrorMessage="Answer is required" runat="server" CssClass="field-validation-error" Display="Dynamic" />

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" CommandName="Submit" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" ValidationGroup="ResetPassword" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <asp:Button ID="cancel" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-block" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="cancel_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <asp:Label ID="FailureText" runat="server" CssClass="field-validation-error" EnableViewState="False" />

  </QuestionTemplate>

  <SuccessTemplate>
    <h2>Reset my password</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Your new password has been sent to your registration email address.</p>
      <p>
        <asp:Button ID="continue" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" runat="server" Text="Continue" OnClick="cancel_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </SuccessTemplate>
</asp:PasswordRecovery>
```

HTML email template:

```html
<body class="auto-style2">
<p>Hi <%FirstName%>.</p>
<p>According to our records... Your new password is: <strong><%Password%></strong></p>
<p>Thank you.</p>
</body>
```

C#:

```
protected void ResetPassword_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
{
    GetUserProfile();
    string firstName = hfFirstName.Value;
    e.Message.Body.Replace("<%FirstName%>", firstName);
}

private void GetUserProfile()
{
    string userName = (Convert.ToString(((TextBox)ResetPassword.Controls[0].FindControl("UserName")).Text));

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlConString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            @"SELECT * 
            FROM [dbo].[User_Profile] UP
            INNER JOIN [Users] U
            ON U.[UserId] = UP.[UserId]
            WHERE U.[UserName] = @userName");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userName", userName));
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader PopulateReader;
            PopulateReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (PopulateReader.Read())
            {
                hfFirstName.Value = (PopulateReader["FirstName"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.InfoFormat("Exception caught in GetUserProfile(): {0}", ex.ToString());
            log.Info(Environment.NewLine + "End Exception" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

I realize the GetUserProfile()/HiddenField method probably isn't the greatest, but it stores and retrieves the correct value for the 'firstName' variable. It would appear the breakdown happens at `e.Message.Body.Replace("<%FirstName%>", firstName);` but I don't get any errors and I can't determine why the placeholder doesn't get replaced. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance for taking a look, and any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: passwords should be hashed so you cant return one,

Comment: @prospector Yes, but when you're *trying to reset the password* you have to be able to grab the unhashed password so the user knows what the new password is.

Comment: @mason - not necessarily true. http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html

Comment: @RobH I'm not reading all of that. Can you summarize the important part? I imagine it's something along the lines of sending a token instead, then having the user reset their password on the site? While that's fine and true, that doesn't really help Barbados here as he tries to embed the reset password in the email.

Comment: FWIW, I wasn't attempting to return the password; I just wanted to add some additional data to the outgoing email, which already included the newly reset password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here: [String is not replaced in CreateUserWizard Registration Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211571/string-is-not-replaced-in-createuserwizard-registration-email).   `e.Message.Body.Replace("<%FirstName%>", firstName);` was incorrect. The correct way is `e.Message.Body = e.Message.Body.Replace("<%FirstName%>", firstName.ToString());`. The placeholder is now correctly replaced with the desired value.  Thanks.